# Param value encoding

Tags: encoding, jmh, sbt-jmh

I have a benchmark in sbt-jmh, which is a "wrapper" for jmh for which I have a parameter that contains non-ASCII characters. It looks like this:

```
@Param(Array("1000", "１000"))
```

That's the equivalent for Java

```
@Param({"1000", "１000"})
```

Note that the second string `"１000"` starts with a full width one character, code point +uFF11

This file is encoded in UTF8. My platform is Windows 8.1, and the platform encoding is cp1252

My `build.sbt` contains `scalacOptions ++= List("encoding", "UTF8")`

I expect very similar benchmark results for both params, but I'm seeing drastically different results, that seem to imply that the second string isn't processed properly.

How can I make sure the benchmark uses the correct string as a parameter?

Comment: Can you provide benchmark results?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Yes, but it's no longer relevant, it was a bug, and is fixed now. I posted that as an answer. See http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2017-March/002508.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in 1.17, and is fixed in 1.18